# Large data set of dates, which are factors and needed to be changed to integers

Tags: r

I have a large data set of dates in the form of factors, i need to be able to change these into integers so that i can further analyse the data. I have tried installing lubridate, and used different pieces of code to try and change the data.

```
fac <- factor(c(pigdata$Sow.Date.Of.Birth))
as.numeric(as.character(fac))
numeric(0)
as.numeric(pigdata$Sow.Date.Of.Birth)
numeric(0)
```

Not sure if im doing it right, would be great to get some help.

Comment: Given that output, `length(pigdata$Sow.Date.Of.Birth)` should return `0`. Have you mispeled the column name?

Comment: Why do you want to convert your dates to numeric variables? Don’t you want to convert your dates into ‘date times’ that you can easily work with using the lubridate package? If you could show us a subset of your data we can help you convert the variable into something you can manipulate.

Comment: Welcome to SO, timo. As Tom mentioned, it would be worthwhile to learn some `lubridate` methods; it's a very powerful package. With your idea, you could force the dates to become numeric, essentially by mapping each one to "days since 1970-01-01", or to some other origin (i.e. `as.numeric(as.Date("2020-02-29") - as.Date("1970-01-01"))`). However, with `ggplot` and `lubridate`, this task becomes very simple. Google search "time series data with lubridate" for examples.